# Check if method implements interface method marked with attribute

Tags: c#, wcf, roslyn

Is it possible with Roslyn to figure out if a class method implements some interface method which was marked with attribute?

Particularly in wcf we describe service contracts using interface. Each method of it should be marked with `OperationContractAttribute` like in following sample

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISimleService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);
}

public class SimleService : ISimleService
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

In Roslyn `ISymbol` interface provides us GetAttributes() method, but called on a `SimleService.GetData()` method it returns 0. Called on `ISimleService.GetData()` declaration it returns `OperationContractAttribute` as expected.

So in general I have to check class hierarchy to find all interfaces implemented and then traverse hierarchy to find appropriate methods.This is a hard way and I guess there should be an easier one.

Comment: In Wcf service the Interfaces are required to mark their methods with attribute `OperationContract`. Instead of searching for interface implementation why not simply look for all interfaces marked with `ServiceContract` and find  all the methods in such interface then apply filter to see if they all are marked as `OperationContract`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it's possible to find out if a method is an implementation of an interface's method. Here's the code to do that:

```
methodSymbol.ContainingType
    .AllInterfaces
     .SelectMany(@interface => @interface.GetMembers().OfType<IMethodSymbol>())
     .Any(method => methodSymbol.Equals(methodSymbol.ContainingType.FindImplementationForInterfaceMember(method)));
```

You can modify this to actually grab the implemented method, and on that you can check the attributes.

Comment: Yes, finally I ended up with something similair